# Cocos2d MenuItem Selector and Accessing Instance Variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have an instance variable declared in the implementation file which can be accessed using the property defined by synthesize

```
@synthesize myProperty
```

Now, I want to assign this property something inside the Selector event of the MenuItem in cocos2d library. You can think of it as a accessing myProperty in a callback function. For some reason whenever I access the property it says "property is out of scope". So I tried to assigned the access the self.myProperty which worked!!

But now I have a memory leak in self.myProperty. If I release self.myProperty in dealloc then it throws an exception saying that I also have myProperty release.

**UPDATE 1: (Code)**

NSString *voice;

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *voice; 
@synthesize voice;

```
-(void)repeatAlphabet:(id)sender 

{
 *// I cannot access the voice variable in this function.* 

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:[[voice lowercaseString] stringByAppendingString:@".caf"]]; 
}

-(void) addRepeatButtonOnScreen 

{

CCMenuItemImage * menuItem1 =[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"image1.png"

selectedImage: @"image2.png"

  target:self

selector:@selector(repeatAlphabet:)];

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1,nil]; 

menu.position = ccp(30, 450); 

[self addChild:menu]; 


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have defined an ivar corresponding to your property also called myProperty, and that your property is either `retain` or `copy`: in your dealloc you should do `[myProperty release];` not `[self.myProperty release]`.

UPDATE: after discussion and more code shown... 'out of scope' can be a symptom of not having retained a value that should be retained. For instance for a string `value = @"Value"` doesn't retain (and will become out of scope), fixed by using `self.value = @"Value"` or `value = [@"Value" retain]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes I do [myProperty release] but since I am using self.myProperty inside the callback function of the MenuItem selector self.myProperty never gets released and it shows memory leak in the instruments application.

Comment: You need to be more specific then by what you mean by 'using' (showing code would help a lot). If your property is synthesized and retain, self.myProperty = value automatically release previous value before retaining, so there is no leak.

Comment: Please check the above updated with code! Thanks for yr help!

Comment: OK and what's the value of voice when there is a problem? How is it setup?

Comment: The value of voice is assigned in a different function. The value usually is just a string like "voice1", "voice2" etc. But when the repeatAlphabet if triggered the variable voice cannot be accessed and it is considered out of scope!

Comment: Do you setup voice using voice = @"..." or object.voice = @"...", ie using the property or directly the ivar? If the ivar directly, it needs to be retained.

Comment: I just use voice = "something";

Comment: That's your bug :) You should either use the property's setter (`self.voice = @"something"`, or `yourObject.voice = @"something"` if in another class) or retain the string using `voice = [@something retain]`). Else the value affected to voice will become undefined at a random point (autorelease).

Comment: Thanks I will try it out and see the outcome!

Comment: I just tried it out and it seemed like it solved the problem! In the dealloc I am still releasing the voice object like this [voice release] will this be okay?

Comment: That's okay yes, else it would leak.